# how to align bottom text to the middle of icons

Tags: html, css

I want to align the bottom text to the icons and make equal spaces between all icons

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLkwt/3/

```
<div id="middle">
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/smart_tv.jpg" align="middle">Smart TV</div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/tablet.jpg" align="middle">Tablet</div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/iphone.jpg" align="middle"></div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/android.jpg" align="middle">Android</div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/pc.jpg" align="middle">Pc</div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/mac.jpg" align="middle">Mac</div>
    <div id="middle_txt">
      <h1>dfgdfgdfgd</h1>
      <div id="middle_border"></div>
      <h2>dfgdfgdfgdg</h2>
    </div><!--close_middle_txt-->
</div><!--middle-->
```

Comment: what do you mean by "thet"?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe, it might be `text`.

Comment: You have asked 3 questions *today* based on the same problem! (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731201/align-text-to-the-center-of-icons (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730574/how-to-align-bottom-text-to-the-middle-of-icons (3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730456/how-to-place-text-under-icon

Comment: `<img align="middle">` is not supported anymore. Browsers will still use it for a while, but at some point this will become obsolete. Use CSS instead if you want a future-proof design. See http://fantasai.tripod.com/qref/HTML4/deprecated.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer on "make equal spaces between all icons part.
First off, I assume all icons (jpgs) have the same dimensions to start with.

You could try to add padding or margin (-left & -right) to let them have the same seperation width:

```
.icon_middle {
    float: right;
    text-align: bottom-center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 85px;
    padding-left: 20;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

But it is unclear to me whether that was your question? Could you maybe give some more context/explenation?

Answer (score 1):

For equal spaces between all icons (images) use padding:

```
img {
  padding: 0 10px; // 10px horizontal padding
}
```

And to align it, use:

```
h1 {
  float: left;
}

h2 {
  float: right;
}
```

For the middle border, I am not sure but if you want a border, then just add this:

```
#middle_border {
  border: 1px solid #999; // or anyother color
}
```

For middle text element use this:

```
#middle_txt {
  text-align: center; // to align its children to the center..
  // or use this:
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto; // it will be placed in the center..
}
```