# align text to the center of icons

Tags: html, css, alignment

i want to align the text under the icons to the icons image

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/J2N2P/

```
<div id="middle">
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/smart_tv.jpg" align="middle" vspace="5"><span>Smart TV</span></div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/tablet.jpg" align="middle" vspace="5"><span>Tablet</span></div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/iphone.jpg" align="middle" vspace="5"><span>Iphone</span></div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/android.jpg" align="middle" vspace="5"><span>Android</span></div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/pc.jpg" align="middle" vspace="5"><span>Pc</span></div>
    <div class="icon_middle"><img src="images/mac.jpg" align="middle" vspace="5"><span>Mac</span></div>
    <div id="middle_txt">
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have tried to make it work and why it did not work. Dont expect people on SO to just write the code for you.

Comment: Maybe update your question with a more relevant jsfiddle? Without icons nor a description this question is not really good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this to your CSS, You'll get align imgs and text in the center:

**CSS**

```
.icon_middle span {
   display:block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align:center;
}

.icon_middle img {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to place pairs img/span within some container (span or div) and then align them relative to that container. Or, if layout is thought to be more like table, just use table/tr/td and align pairs of img/span within td.